# Which process in android asks ActivityManager to broadcast BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, android-activity, android-logcat

I have searched this over the web, without an answer. Basically while testing a device, I observe that the display screen fires ON much earlier, while in the logcat the print 
Consoleui:bootComplete follows after ~ 8 sec.

Now Device screen is displayed as part of starting Launcher application, so in the natural sequence of events, the system server will ask activitymanager to start launcher in a seperate thread and go on doing more work.

Thus it is only natural that display will come up, but still there might remain some services to be started by activitymanager/systemserver before a BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast can be made.

I have to prove this. In order to do so, I need to know which process tells the activitymanager that now it can broadcast the boot_complete message, if its the system server, please tell me the part of code where it does so. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Alex, I want to prove, say to a layman, that the time device's display turns ON has got nothing to do with the time the "boot complete" print comes in logcat,

Comment: Try explaining to them how the `init.rc` boot script works then: http://elinux.org/Android_Booting

Comment: Maybe i was a little wrong in saying i want to explain it to a layman, lets take a scenario, where i am a developer and a QA guy filed a bug that bootComplete print comes much later than the display turning ON, basically lets say he thinks display should ideally come up after the bootComplete print comes...so i would want  to show him using code snippets from the source code how these two events aren;t tightly bound to each other :)

Comment: Here is the source code for the [`ActivityManagerService`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java)... you might be able to find some stuff in there. I doubt picking out a specific piece of source code will prove much though... whoever you are trying to convince is not going to be able to obtain a clear picture of how the boot process works just from a few of lines of code. The system startup process is complex and involves a lot of interactions between system services...

Comment: Lets take a starting point...so system server tells Activity Manager to start a couple of services..of this will also be the launcher..which i suppose gives the print that "Launcher has been displayed", so after all these services are started by activity manager and mediaserver...someone...i guess system server will initiate a broadcast that boot has got completed...i just want to know which process that is :)

Comment: System services are not created as entirely separate processes... in fact, most of the system services (i.e. activity manager, power manager, window manager, etc.) are part of the system server process itself. It looks like most of the setup you are referring to though is done inside the `ActivityManagerService` though (see my answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The activity manager service sends the boot complete intent on line 6320 of [`ActivityManagerService.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java).

The activity manager service also starts the launcher using an intent with `CATEGORY_HOME` on line 3305 of [`ActivityManagerService.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java).

Comment: So its the ActivityManager that broadcasts an intent that bootComplete has happened...so who tells the activitymanager to broadcast bootComplete intent, does it do that itself, or system server process after starting all services(as threads within itself) tells the activitymanager to initiate the broadcasting process of "bootCompleted".

Comment: @Tanmay - Alex answered your question. You should accept his answer. If you have a new question, then you should ask a new question. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @jww I am really glad about the inputs alex has given..but my original question still remains unanswered as i have reiterated in the comment above..i think alex knows the answer..waiting for him to tell me

Comment: @TanmayVarun I'm not sure when and where these events are triggered... you'd probably have to be an Android framework engineer at Google in order to answer that question. There is a great book called [Embedded Android](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do) though that I would highly recommend if you want more insight on how Android's boot sequence works.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your original question contains 2 sub-questions:

Q1. Where exactly in the AOSP code is system broadcast Intent BOOT_COMPLETED fired?

Q2. What are all the necessary conditions to trigger the firing of BOOT_COMPLETED?

For Q1, a broad location is in the Activity Manager. In this sense, @Alex Lockwood’s answer is correct. However, I have noticed that the exact location and the way this Intent is fired may change between Android versions. A source code search should be able to lead to the answer. Take AOSP branch “android-8.1.0_r32” as an example. First, find out where file “ActivityManagerService.java” is located using the following shell commands:

$ cd [your AOSP branch’s root directory]

$ find . -name ActivityManagerService.java

Once the file is found, go to its parent directory. For example, in our current case:

$ cd frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am

Now perform the following search:

$ grep -rIn ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED .

The output reveals that the exact location is not in file “ActivityManagerService.java”, but in file “UserController.java”. More exactly, it is in method “UserController.finishUserUnlockedCompleted()”.

For Q2, we can search backwards from the above method. Eventually we may reach method “ActivityManagerService.finishBooting()” where we can see that Boolean “mBootAnimationComplete” must be true. This implies that the boot animation process must be completed in order for BOOT_COMPLETED to be fired, and further implies that while the boot animation process is going on, a lot of system services are being started. For further details, you may refer to some dedicated books that explain which system services must be ready in order for the boot animation process to end.